# how to extract a value from an ordered dictionary of tuples, that changes order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a list of ordered items, which changes, and i want to extract the list color value which in this case is [rrr,ggg,bbb].  r g and b are colour intensity values from 0 - 255.

This list can be like this

```
o_list = [('d',2), ('color', {'col':[255,042,072]}), ('s',0), ('l',{'a':10, 'b':20})]
```

or like this...

```
o_list = [('color', {'col':[230,132,150]}), ('d',2), ('s',0), ('l',{'a':10, 'b':20})]
```

If I use index location, sometimes the type will be an int, sometimes will be a dict or list, or int, or tuple.

What is the quickest way to search for the colour in the list [rrr,ggg,bbb] and extract it ?

Comment: `050,050,050` probably is a string. Can you confirm it else it will throw error?

Comment: What about `dict(o_list)['color']['col']`?

Comment: Adding a bit to @bigbounty's comment: In Python 3, integer-like symbols with a leading zero will cause `SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`. But in Python2, they're treated as integers with an octal representation (so `050 == 40`). Which is the case here?

Comment: [050,050,050] is a list of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to transform the list to a dict and then get the color:

```
dict(o_list).get('color').get('col')
```

returns exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `filter()` and `.get()` like this:

```
o_list = [('d',2), ('color', {'col':["050","050","050"]}), ('s',0), ('l',{'a':10, 'b':20})]

def filter_col_tuple(tup):
    k,v = tup
    if k == 'color':
        return True
    else: 
        return False

filtered = filter(filter_col_tuple, o_list)
print(next(filtered)[1].get('col'))
```

What this does is create a filter-object (`filtered`), which can be iterated. However, it only has one value so we directly get the first value with calling `next()` on it. Then we use `[1]` to get the second value of the tuple, and use `.get()` get the value of key 'col' in the dictionary.

I assumed that the `050` should be considered a string, as it isn't a valid integer.

Bonus: using lambda in your filter() is also possible, like this:

```
o_list = [('d',2), ('color', {'col':["050","050","050"]}), ('s',0), ('l',{'a':10, 'b':20})]
filtered = filter(lambda x: x[0]=='color', o_list)
print(next(filtered)[1].get('col'))
```

Comment: it is [r,g,b] so each is an integer value from 0 to 255.  They are the intensity levels of each pixel

Comment: Ok but please be aware that `050` is not an integer value in Python.